# can we have back button in a ModalViewController?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

is it possible to have a back button in a modal viewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to make it yourself. If your modal controller has a navigation bar, put a button and give it an action like this:

```
- (IBAction)myBackButtonPressed {
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the parentView viewController, where puchviewController is called, specify this compare title string:

```
if ([textString length] < 1)
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Back";
}
else
{
    self.navigationItem.title = textString;
}
```

Or you can also set:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Back";
```

directly in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.